# Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Skripsi\public\Member\profile.php on line 37

Tags: php, validation

After i check it with echo "$_SESSION('success')"; it says my Session is in array. $_SESSION('success') is filled with username, after Login.

```
<?php
      $uname=$_SESSION("success");
      $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `msuser` WHERE `Username` = '".$uname."' AND `Status` > 0");
      if($sql->num_rows>0)
      {
        while($row=$sql->fetch_assoc())
        {
          ?>
          <table>
          <tr>
              <td>Username:<?php echo $row["Username"]; ?></td>
          </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name:<?php echo $row["Name"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Email:<?php echo $row["Email"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Address:<?php echo $row["Address"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Phone: <?php echo $row["Phone"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Role:<?php echo $row["Role"] ?></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        <?php
        }
      }
        ?>
```

Here is my Login Validation code:

$uname=$_POST["uname"];

$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `msuser` WHERE `Username` = '".$uname."' AND `Password` = md5('".$pass."') AND `Status` > 0");
        if($sql->num_rows>0)
        {
            setcookie(user,$pass,time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
            $_COOKIE[user];

```
        while($row=$sql->fetch_assoc())
        {
            if($row["Role"] == "Admin")
            {
                $_SESSION["success"]=$uname;
                header("Location: ../../../public/Admin/home.php");
            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION["success"]=$uname;
                header("Location: ../../../public/Member/home.php");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you mean `$_SESSION['success']` ?

Comment: $_SESSION('success') is not the way to get session value I think. Its an array so try using $_SESSION['success']. to check its value use print_r($_SESSION);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP [Session](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) variable format is like `$_SESSION['variable_name']`

So in your case it should be `$_SESSION['success']` and not `$_SESSION("success");`

And by the way, have you started the session with `session_start();`?

Comment: any idea what happen?
i change it like this, and it still says: Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Skripsi\public\Member\profile.php on line 38

$uname = $_SESSION('success');
      $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `msuser` WHERE `Username` = '".$uname."' AND `Status` > 0");

Comment: It seems you haven't changed! change `$_SESSION('success');` to `$_SESSION['success']`